# Laravel 3/4 Save DB object in Database

Tags: php, object, serialization, laravel

I am trying to figure out how to build a query with laravel's query builder, and save the query builder object.

Something like this:

```
    // Build Query
$query = DB::table('users');
$query->join('table', 'users.id', '=', 'table.users_id');
$query->where('id', '=', 1);
// ...

// Encode DB object and save to DB 
$save = serialize($query);

// Get from DB
$get = unserialize($save);

$get->get();
```

This throws Exception: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed.

Does anyone have a way to do this?  Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can't afaik, you can use `toSql()` to get the query though.

Comment: May I ask why? There might be a better way of doing what you're trying to do.

Comment: So users can build the reports and save the setup. I suppose toSql() would be the same though without the ability to edit...or add to the setup.  I did write a class that does this but I was curious about other possible approaches too. Any good ideas?